# Очистка строки, удаление одиночных символов апострофов из списка слов содержащих апостроф

Tags: python, список, фильтрация

Всех приветствую!

Есть некие трудности в обработки списков. Предположим есть список:

```
words = ["we're", "'", "'''", "he's", "'abc", "ghe'", 'hello', "'h", "h'"]
```

Необходимо удалить только одиночные апострофы из списка, не затрагивая слова содержащие апострофы. Пробелов в списке нет, как и других символов из набора:

```
from string import punctuation
```

Результат должен выглядеть так:

```
result_words = ["we're", "he's", "'abc", "ghe'", 'hello', "'h", "h'"]
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: одиночные - нет букв ни с какой стороны или достаточно с одной?

Comment: одиночные - нет букв ни с какой стороны, наличие одной буквы с любой стороны имеет в общем представление слова с апострофом, например ["h'"] или ["'h"] будут словами с апострофом, у которых апостроф удалять не нужно.

Comment: посмотрите regex Negative Lookahead и Negative  Lookbehind. Там все очень просто

Comment: @splash58 спасибо за наводку, изучаю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
words = ["we're", "'", "'''", "he's", "'abc", "ghe'", 'hello', "'h", "h'"]

res = ([x for x in words if "".join(set(x))!="'"])
print(res)
```

> ["we're", "he's", "'abc", "ghe'", 'hello', "'h", "h'"]

Comment: Огромное спасибо, данное решение для меня отлично подходит. Все же стоит для себя изучить регулярные выражения тоже :^)

Answer (score 2):

Ещё как вариант - проверка, что слово состоит не только из символов пунктуации (хотя в вашем случае нужно проверять только апострофы, но обычно задача ставится немного шире):

```
from string import punctuation

words = ["we're", "'", "'''", "he's", "'abc", "ghe'", 'hello', "'h", "h'"]
result_words = [w for w in words if set(w) - set(punctuation)]
print(result_words)
```

Вывод:

```
["we're", "he's", "'abc", "ghe'", 'hello', "'h", "h'"]
```